# Trying to detect when a user leaves so the discord bot can leave

Tags: discord.js

So here I want my music bot to leave a vc when no one is in the vc anymore. It does work but someone it repeats the leaving process twice. I have tried tinkering it but couldn't find the problem why it would leave twice! Here is my code:

```js
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core-discord");

exports.run = async (client, message, args, ops) => {

  const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

  if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send("Hm... I don't see you in a Voice Channel! Please connect to a voice channel before executing this command!");

  if (message.guild.me.voice.channel) return message.channel.send("Smh! I am already playing in another vc!");

  let validate = await ytdl.validateURL("Some Link");

  if(!validate) return message.channel.send("This stream seems to be unaivalable, please try again later!");

  let connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();

  let dispatcher = await connection.play(await ytdl("Some Link"), { type: 'opus' });

  message.channel.send('Now Playing Some **Some Stream** by Some Person');

  client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel
    let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel


    if(oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {

       // User Joins a voice channel
        console.log("Staying in VC");

    } else if(newUserChannel === undefined){
      try{
        if (voiceChannel) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log("Leaving a VC!")
                message.guild.me.voice.channel.leave();
            }, 3000)
        }
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a few issues with your code, with `newUserChannel` and `oldUserChannel` you should change it to.

```js
let newUserChannel = newMember.channel
let oldUserChannel = oldMember.channel
```

And futher down when you're checking the status of `oldUserChannel` and `newUserChannel` instead of checking it against `undefined`, check it against null:

```js
if(oldUserChannel === null && newUserChannel !== null) { ... }
```

And within your try...catch you should change the sanity check to `newUserChannel`

```js
try {
        if (newUserChannel) {
```

Full Code

```js
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    let newUserChannel = newMember.channel
    let oldUserChannel = oldMember.channel

    if(oldUserChannel === null && newUserChannel !== null) {
        console.log("Staying in VC");
    } else if(newUserChannel === null){
      try{
        if (newUserChannel) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log("Leaving a VC!")
                message.guild.me.voice.channel.leave();
            }, 3000)
        }
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  });
```